How to combine mosaic plots (vcd) and maintain labels?
I am trying to combine a series of mosaic plots produced through vcd::mosaic.
As I cannot use par(mfrow()) to distribure the graphs in a 2 by 2 figure, I used grid.grab() after producing the mosaic plots and adding to them the labels for the  frequencies using labeling_cells. I was inspired by this post here.
The code is the following:
mos<- function(bcoh, sex1, name, union2,m){ 
data2<-dataset_full_paper2_101 %>%
dplyr::filter(birthc==bcoh & sex=-sex1 & union==union2)

genga<-xtabs (~edu34+edu34_pa, data=data2)
t2<-round(prop.table(genga),2)

t3<-data.frame(t2)
t3$edu34<-as.numeric(t3$edu34)
t3$edu34_pa<- as.numeric(t3$edu34_pa)

genga2<-structable(~edu34+edu34_pa, data=t3) 
dimnames (genga2)<-list (edu34=c(1,2,3),edu34_pa=c(1,2,3))
txt<-as.table(matrix(paste0(t2), 3,3))
dimnames (txt)=dimnames (genga2)
colors=c("#d1e8e2", "#d1e8e2","#d1e8e2","#a9d6ca", "#a9d6ca", "#a9d6ca","#7cc7c0", "#7cc7c0", "#7cc7c0")

mosaic(x=genga2, pop-F, direction='v', gp-gpar (fill=colors), colorize=T, shade=T,
labeling_args=list(set_varnames=c(edu34="Education",
edu34_pa="Partner's education")),set_labels=c(list(edu34=c("Low", "Interm","High"), edu34_pa=c("Low", "Interm", "High")))
labeling_cells(text=txt, margin=0,clip=T)(genga2) 
m=grid.grab()
}

mos (0,2, "Married women born in 1932-1950",2,m1) 
mos (1,2, "Married women born in 1951-1970",2,m2) 
grid. arrange(m1,m2)

However, when it comes to combining the graphs I incur into this error.
mos (0,2, "Married women born in 1932-1950",2,m1) warning messages:

1: In grabDL (warn, wrap, wrap.grobs, ...) :
viewport overwritten (grab MAY not be faithful) 
2: In grabDL (warn, wrap, wrap.grobs, ...) :
viewport overwritten (grab MAY not be faithful) 

mos (1,2, "Married women born in 1951-1970",2,m2) warning messages:
1: In grabDL (warn, wrap, wrap.grobs, ...) : 
viewport overwritten (grab MAY not be faithful) 
2: In grabDL (warn, wrap, wrap.grobs, ...) :
viewport overwritten (grab MAY not be faithful)

grid. arrange(m1,m2)
Error in gList(...) : only 'grobs' allowed in "gList"

If someone could help me in finding a solution, I would really appreciate.
Thank you very much!
